# backtick is not found in search for element

Tags: java, selenium, appium, element

I tried to find the right solution in Java on how to find the element with the backtick
[image: element pictures] I tried to add to the inner text just ' and in wrap all with " " and nothing helps, the element is not found, what do i missed?
Thanks

Comment: `'` (apostophe) != `\`` (grave accent, aka backtick)

Comment: yes I know it's differ from apostophe

Comment: So which is it? Question title and text says "backtick", but then talks about `'`, which is an apostrophe, so of course it doesn't find a backtick, if you write the code to look for apostrophe.

Comment: I want to use all of that locator, and it looks that the backtick fails the locator

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what that first selector is trying to do. The second selector correctly shows how to filter on the value of an attribute named `name`. The first selector just looks like a syntax error to me. As far as I know, xpath doesn't use backtick for anything, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I want to use the first selector since there is very much difference in timing between xpath and the one's of IOS (around 1000 ms) but than I have the thing with the backtick, is it part of the string? how should I write it?

Comment: Well, there is the **apostrophe** (**'**) and then there is also the [Diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) glyphs named the **[Grave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)** (** `** - [U+0060 or U+02CB or U+02F4] aka: the Back Tick) and the **[Acute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent)** (**´**  - [U+00B4 or U+02CA] aka: the Forward Tick). Which one is it?

Comment: @DevilsHnd  Grave (** `** - [U+0060 or U+02CB or U+02F4] aka: the Back Tick)

Comment: `if (theString.contains("\u0060label ==") || theString.contains("\u02CBlabel ==")) { // Found it! }`

Answer (score 1):

you can add `'` with the escape character `\`.
eg if you want to add 'label then it should be    `"\'"+"label"`

Comment: so to add that backtick I need to add "\" ?

Comment: \ its called escape character for '